# Position of Matplotlib Pyplot bar chart labels not consistent with nan values

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm plotting bar charts of data that contains missing values (np.nan).  It seems as though when the np.nan value appears in the last category, the x-axis ticks are positioned differently than when there are no np.nans or when the NaN values are in a different position.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

years = np.array([2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])
x = np.arange(len(years))
y1 = np.array([ 29.,  10.,  16.,  29., np.nan])
y2 = np.array([ 29.,  10.,  np.nan,  29., 16.])
y3 = np.array([ np.nan,  29., 29.,  10.,  16.])

f = plt.figure(figsize=(4,6))

ax = f.add_subplot(311)
ax.bar(x, y1, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

ax = f.add_subplot(312)
ax.bar(x, y2, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

ax = f.add_subplot(313)
ax.bar(x, y3, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output in jupyter notebook]

Ideally, I would like the x-axis labels to be in the same place, regardless of whether there are NaN values in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a specific range on the plot, you can just set it explicitly. After each block add, e.g.

```
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, years.size - 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

replace the y1, y2, y3 arrays with `np.nan_to_num(y1)` ...etc